# MacBook Air stuck on windows

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp

I was attempting to download Windows on my MacBook and it was successful so far. The Windows desktop loaded in and everything. Now came to the part where Bootcamp was once again asking to install, I said yes but halfway while it was installing it suddenly cancelled out on me. I also didn’t have network since mine was not appearing and I figured I would fix it afterwards.

How do I get back to MacOS now? I still have BootCamp files in the files for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key on the keyboard while starting up?

Comment: just tried it, allowed me to exit. Thank you!